# How can I ask for user input (file path to a ZIP archive) in my ZSH script with full auto-completion via TAB?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 (ZSH) on my Mac.

How can I ask for user input (file path to a ZIP archive) in my ZSH script with full auto-completion via TAB?

My current code:

```
vared -p "Enter your Archive Path: " -c ARCHIVE_PATH
```

Auto-completion via TAB works than only for directories...the last directory contains the ZIP archive...a listing of the files in this last directory doesn't work.